# RadDatePicker in ASP.NET Gridview TemplateField

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dotnetnuke

I've got a date picker field declared within a template field in a GridView as follows:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Shipping Date">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblShippingDate" runat="server" CssClass="dnnFormLabel" 
            AssociatedControlID="ShippingDatePicker" />
        <dnn:DnnDatePicker runat="server" ID="ShippingDatePicker" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I can select the date just fine and it appears in my label control - I then click on a standard *asp:Button* which finds the selected row and despite it finding all the other controls on the row including the label control displaying the selected date, the label's *Text* attribute is blank:

```
var txtShippingDate = row.Cells[7].FindControl("lblShippingDate") as Label;
```

Please note that I'm using the DotNetNuke *dnn:DnnDatePicker* control but this is actually a *RadDatePicker* under the covers.

Can anyone suggest how I can successfully read the value?

Thanks for looking :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following after you find label:

```
if(txtShippingDate != null) {
    string date = Request.Form[txtShippingDate.UniqueID].ToString();
}
```